# Can't unescape scraped HTML document

Tags: c#, html, escaping

I am trying to unescape [this](https://www.examenblad.nl/examenrooster/2018?api=get_filtered_exam_table&a=%7B%22periode%22:%22tijdvak%22,%22dag%22:%2210-05-2017%22,%22tijdvakken%22:[%22vg41h1h4i9pl%22,%22vg41h1h4i9pm%22],%22sectoren%22:[%22vg41h1h4i9qe%22,%22vg41h1h4i9qd%22,%22vga6k854m5p9%22,%22vga3db3c9od8%22,%22vga3db3c9od6%22,%22vga3db3c9od5%22],%22filterjaarid%22:%22viwvlbcs3nyv%22%7D) HTML document with C# so that I can retrieve data from it later.

I tried unescaping the document with the following functions:

```
var url = @"...";

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url4);
```

- `Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape()`
- `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`
- `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape()`

However none of these methods seem to do anything. Is there something I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried printing it to screen instead of inspecting it when you step through?  I think when you step through and view it as a property, it keeps the outside quotes around to show you the string value, but when you actually use the property, the outside quotes should be gone so the rest of the double quotes won't be escaped

Comment: @Pete, You're absolutely right! Stupid mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html all `\`s, `"`s and `/`s are escaped.

You can use

```
html = Regex.Unescape(html);
```

That will return you a *clean* html

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.examenblad.nl/examenrooster/2018?api=get_filtered_exam_table&a=%7B%22periode%22:%22tijdvak%22,%22dag%22:%2210-05-2017%22,%22tijdvakken%22:[%22vg41h1h4i9pl%22,%22vg41h1h4i9pm%22],%22sectoren%22:[%22vg41h1h4i9qe%22,%22vg41h1h4i9qd%22,%22vga6k854m5p9%22,%22vga3db3c9od8%22,%22vga3db3c9od6%22,%22vga3db3c9od5%22],%22filterjaarid%22:%22viwvlbcs3nyv%22%7D");
html = Regex.Unescape(html);
```

Final html

```
    "
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="styletable">

<tr class="bg rij1">
<th class="fontwit cel1">Datum</th>
<th class="fontwit">Tijd</th>
<th class="fontwit">Examen</th>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">%tijdvak1sep%</td>

<td class="fontwit">&nbsp;</td>

<td class="fontwit">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/engels-bb-vmbo/2018">Engels BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/nederlands-kb-vmbo/2018">Nederlands KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/nederlands-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">Nederlands GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/natuurkunde-havo-2/2018">natuurkunde, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-a-vwo/2018">wiskunde A, vwo (bezemexamen)</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-a-vwo-2/2018">wiskunde A, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-b-vwo/2018">wiskunde B, vwo (bezemexamen)</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-b-vwo-2/2018">wiskunde B, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-c-vwo/2018">wiskunde C, vwo (bezemexamen)</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 14 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-c-vwo-2/2018">wiskunde C, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 15 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/muziek-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">muziek GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 15 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/geschiedenis-havo-3/2018">geschiedenis, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 15 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/geschiedenis-vwo-3/2018">geschiedenis, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 15 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/economie-bb-vmbo/2018">economie BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 15 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-kb-vmbo/2018">wiskunde KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 15 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">wiskunde GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 15 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/engels-havo-2/2018">Engels, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 15 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/frans-vwo/2018">Frans, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-10:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/geschiedenis-en-staatsinrichting-3/2018">geschiedenis en staatsinrichting BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/geschiedenis-en-staatsinrichting-2/2018">geschiedenis en staatsinrichting KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/geschiedenis-en-staatsinrichting/2018">geschiedenis en staatsinrichting GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/filosofie-havo/2018">filosofie, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/maatschappij-wetenschappen-vwo/2018">maatschappij­wetenschappen, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/maatschappij-wetenschappen-vwo-2/2018">maatschappij­wetenschappen, vwo (pilot)</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/nederlands-bb-vmbo/2018">Nederlands BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/engels-kb-vmbo/2018">Engels KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/engels-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">Engels GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/handvaardigheid-havo/2018">handvaardigheid, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/textiele-vormgeving-havo/2018">textiele vormgeving, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/tekenen-havo/2018">tekenen, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 16 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/engels-vwo-2/2018">Engels, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-10:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/aardrijkskunde-bb-vmbo-2/2018">aardrijkskunde BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/duits-kb-vmbo/2018">Duits KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/duits-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">Duits GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/muziek-havo/2018">muziek, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/latijnse-taal-en-cultuur-vwo/2018">Latijnse taal en cultuur, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-bb-vmbo/2018">wiskunde BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/biologie-kb-vmbo/2018">biologie KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/biologie-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">biologie GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/nederlands-havo-2/2018">Nederlands, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 17 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/scheikunde-vwo-2/2018">scheikunde, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 18 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-10:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/duits-bb-vmbo/2018">Duits BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 18 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/aardrijkskunde-kb-vmbo-2/2018">aardrijkskunde KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 18 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/aardrijkskunde-gl-en-tl-vmbo-2/2018">aardrijkskunde GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 18 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/duits-havo/2018">Duits, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 18 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/filosofie-vwo/2018">filosofie, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 18 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/natuur-en-scheikunde-ii-gl-en-tl/2018">natuur- en scheikunde II GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 18 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/economie-havo-2/2018">economie, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 18 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/nederlands-vwo-2/2018">Nederlands, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/maatschappijkunde-kb-vmbo/2018">maatschappijkunde KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/maatschappijkunde-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">maatschappijkunde GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/aardrijkskunde-havo/2018">aardrijkskunde, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/duits-vwo/2018">Duits, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/frans-bb-vmbo/2018">Frans BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/frans-kb-vmbo/2018">Frans KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/frans-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">Frans GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/frans-havo/2018">Frans, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 22 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/biologie-vwo-2/2018">biologie, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-10:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/maatschappijkunde-bb-vmbo/2018">maatschappijkunde BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/beeldende-vorming-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">beeldende vorming GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/kunst-algemeen-havo/2018">kunst (algemeen), havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/griekse-taal-en-cultuur-vwo/2018">Griekse taal en cultuur, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/natuur-en-scheikunde-i-bb-vmbo/2018">natuur- en scheikunde I BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/economie-kb-vmbo/2018">economie KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/economie-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">economie GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/management-en-organisatie-havo/2018">management en organisatie, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">woensdag 23 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/economie-vwo-2/2018">economie, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/dans-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">dans GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/drama-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">drama GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/voertuigentechniek-gl-vmbo/2018">voertuigentechniek GL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/transport-en-logistiek-gl-vmbo/2018">transport en logistiek GL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/aardrijkskunde-vwo-2/2018">aardrijkskunde, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/biologie-bb-vmbo/2018">biologie BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/natuur-en-scheikunde-i-kb-vmbo/2018">natuur- en scheikunde I KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/natuur-en-scheikunde-i-gl-en-tl/2018">natuur- en scheikunde I GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-a-havo-2/2018">wiskunde A, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/wiskunde-b-havo-2/2018">wiskunde B, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">donderdag 24 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/natuurkunde-vwo-2/2018">natuurkunde, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/fries-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">Fries GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/maatschappij-wetenschappen-havo/2018">maatschappij­wetenschappen, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/maatschappij-wetenschappen-havo-2/2018">maatschappij­wetenschappen, havo (pilot)</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/muziek-vwo-2/2018">muziek, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/spaans-bb-vmbo/2018">Spaans BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/turks-bb-vmbo/2018">Turks BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/arabisch-bb-vmbo/2018">Arabisch BB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/spaans-kb-vmbo/2018">Spaans KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/turks-kb-vmbo/2018">Turks KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/arabisch-kb-vmbo/2018">Arabisch KB, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/spaans-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">Spaans GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/turks-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">Turks GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-15:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/arabisch-gl-en-tl-vmbo/2018">Arabisch GL en TL, vmbo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/scheikunde-havo-3/2018">scheikunde, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">vrijdag 25 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/management-en-organisatie-vwo/2018">management en organisatie, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 28 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-12:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/kunst-algemeen-vwo/2018">kunst (algemeen), vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 28 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/biologie-havo-3/2018">biologie, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 28 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/handvaardigheid-vwo/2018">handvaardigheid, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 28 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/textiele-vormgeving-vwo/2018">textiele vormgeving, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">maandag 28 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/tekenen-vwo/2018">tekenen, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/fries-havo/2018">Fries, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/russisch-havo/2018">Russisch, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/fries-vwo-2/2018">Fries, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">09:00-11:30</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/russisch-vwo-2/2018">Russisch, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/spaans-havo/2018">Spaans, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/turks-havo/2018">Turks, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/arabisch-havo/2018">Arabisch, havo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/spaans-vwo-2/2018">Spaans, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/turks-vwo-2/2018">Turks, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

<tr class="bg">
<td class="fontwit cel1">dinsdag 29 mei 2018</td>
<td class="fontwit">13:30-16:00</td>
<td class="fontwit"><a href="/examen/arabisch-vwo-2/2018">Arabisch, vwo</a></td>

</tr>

</table>

"
```